# How do you move motor car forward for set amount of time and turning left/right

Tags: arduino-uno

Am new to Arduino, wanted to know how to give motor direction to move and the duration of those movements. Goal is to move forward for say 5 seconds, turn left, move for 0.5 seconds, turn right, move for 5 seconds.

```
void loop() {
  //turn on motor A
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  analogWrite(ENA, 100);
  //turn on motor B
  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  analogWrite(ENB, 100);
  delay(1000);

  analogWrite(ENA, 100); //speed 0 - 255
  analogWrite(ENB, 100); //speed 0 - 255
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
  delay(5000);


  analogWrite(ENA, 100); //speed 0 - 255
  analogWrite(ENB, 100); //speed 0 - 255
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  delay(500);

  analogWrite(ENA, 100); //speed 0 - 255
  analogWrite(ENB, 100); //speed 0 - 255
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
  delay(500);

  analogWrite(ENA, 100); //speed 0 - 255
  analogWrite(ENB, 100); //speed 0 - 255
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
  delay(5000);
```

Comment: do you have a question about your program? .... it is unclear why you posted the program listing ........... your program looks vaguely familiar ..... you named  the `output` pins `in1`, `in2` etc.  ..... that sort of thing sticks in memory

Comment: Are you following a specific tutorial? There are plenty of good ones available. Let us know what you have achieved so far. For example, have you got a motor connected and spinning? What code did you use for that? Please delete any non-applicable code and give us what you have done so far.